# Data transfer between two simulink models

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there a way to transfer signals from a `simulink` model to an other of it? I have a model that runs in `external mode` and I need to transfer its output to an other independent model.

Comment: How do you propose to run each model?  Different instances of Matlab?

Comment: Model that sends signal in external mode and in an other model when I run it I receive what first model sends. It is like to create a communication channel between these two models.

Comment: Using UDP is a common approach, but available blocks depend on what Blosksets/Toolboxes you are licensed for.  An example using the instrument control toolbox is given at http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/examples/basic-udp-communication.html